# Combine Bar and Line Chart in Javascript

Tags: javascript, charts

First:  Please Be Gentle, I am a newb with JS

I have a dashboard and I'm creating a chart with JS.  I'm working from a template which already had some examples, so I am making things work by following what was already there.

I have a bar chart but I would like to add a line chart over top of it.

Is this possible?  And if so, how?

I believe I'm using Chart.min.js (imported earlier in doc)

Here is my js (minus the data) to generate the chart.

```
<script>
window.onload = function(){
    // Bar Chart from barChartData
    var ctx = document.getElementById("chart-bar").getContext("2d");
    window.myBar = new Chart(ctx).Bar(barChartData, {
    responsive : true
    });
</script>
```

Hoping someone can help me out with this...  I'm good with the HTML, Python, Flask, MySql, etc.....  but js is still brand new, but I'm learning :-).

Comment: Hey @PerryDaPlatypus do you have a restriction in using charts.js or it was your requirement to use a JS charting library? or else you can checkout http://www.fusioncharts.com/charts/combination-charts-single-y/ or http://www.fusioncharts.com/charts/combination-charts-dual-y.  I am afraid ,I am not much aquaintainted to work with charts.js and cant help you much on there.

Comment: Thanks ayan, for the response.  I don't have a requirement to use it.  I just have a complete examples (html, js, etc.) for this so it is was the easiest place to start.  I'll check out the fusionchart link above and see if it makes sense to me.     My JS is weak, so complete examples that I can just modify are my basic MO right now....

Comment: Cool! Check this exhaustive list of chart fiddles of combination charts, which you play with to see how it suits your requirement. just open any of the fiddle and start checking it out. Link - http://www.fusioncharts.com/javascript-chart-fiddles/?fusioncharts-xt&type=combination-charts

Comment: Looks great!  Looks like it costs about $199 for two sites.  I'd love to make this work with open libraries but I may not be able to....

Comment: I guess its free for the non-commerical use. I have used it in some of my previous open-source non-commercial projects too. Although if you are using this for some commercial use, you might reconsider your opinion. Good stuff about this library was its list of attributes. Just by simply toogling the values you get desired visuals and might not need some acute expertise in JS. Good luck! :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Yes it is possible**.

Chart.js lets you create charts with multiple datasets. The datasets don't have to be of the same type so you can create one dataset with lines and another one with bars like this:

```
datasets: [{
        // set one for your bars
        type: 'bar',
        data: [1, 2, 3, ... ] // your data for the bar chart
      }, {
        // set two for your lines
        type: 'line',
        data: [4, 5, 6, ... ] // your data for the line chart
      }]
```

and then create the chart with those datasets

```
window.myBar = new Chart(ctx, {
        type: 'bar',
        data: barChartData,
        responsive : true,
        // other settings ...
      });
```

You can take some inspiration from my working example [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/xuzGN84T02aLNkOiN7g8?p=preview)

Comment: Thank you very much